# How can it be that a moderator asks offensive questions and closes a valid question?

Tags: discussion, quality

What is wrong with the discourse level here? Why is everyone trying to be a dick? Why are moderators asking offensive and antisocial questions and close valid questions, instead of being helpful and kind? I am basically asked, if I am an idiot.

Why does this ugly culture of being offensive, insulting and dumb exist here? Why all the gatekeeping? Does anyone improve from being insulted? Just curious. Asking for a friend.

Comment: I read such question and Joe's answer, and must say that I agree with what Joe said. Nobody is harassing you, and if anyone asks questions is because we want to help you better and give you better answers. Also, reading your comments on the question, and reading this meta post, I must say that they don't seem constructive, and give the impression that you are caught in a negative situation and are *not* handling it well.... thus why you are venting here. Please, refrain from venting or writing unconstructive comments/posts.

Comment: Now, regarding the Q, please clarify what users ask and give more details if able/prompted, so we can work out useful answers. I rolled back an edit you did to the Q, as it added nothing positive. I'll see if I can edit your Q into a better shape so the Community considers reopening it. In the meantime, perhaps take a break and a deep breath... we are not trolling you... we are here to help... people ask for clarification very often... "should I" questions are off topic and will be closed eventually...

Comment: Done! I think I reworded it without it loosing it's meaning and core idea. Please check it out and feel free to edit it if I missed anything relevant. I also submitted it to reopening (I could mod-open it, but I want the Community to have a say here... and also to show you a small lesson that being polite and having faith in the Community goes a long way ;).

Comment: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7229/73791 here it is, the reopen request

Comment: (oh and yes, no Mod closed your question, it was The Community... in other words, 5 users voted to close it... in the same way users can now vote to reopen it... "I love democracy" - Senator Palpatine)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks for the effort. Appreciated. Going to sleep that over and reflect on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @DarkCygnus given the new comments, I fear the effort may go to waste

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul hmm... well, as a Mod I gladly give up some of my spare time for free with the hopes to improve this Community. Sometimes those efforts work, sometimes... not so much

Comment: @DarkCygnus I really hope you feel better now.

Answer (score 7):

Presumably you mean this question?
[Should I stay and try to improve the workplace or move on?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/192374/should-i-stay-and-try-to-improve-the-workplace-or-move-on)

I don't see where any moderator asked any question. I do see where a few folks asked for clarification about how you got "tricked", and you decided to take offense.

And "should I do A or B" questions get closed all the time, as they are purely opinion, and thus considered off-topic here.

If you actually want an answer to your original question, try editing it into an on-topic format as suggested in the close message:
"Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision."

If instead you are just looking to vent, then good luck with that.

Comment: The process of erring up is not understood. The idea that a question has to be asked in a certain way, is just hostile gatekeeping and a form of censorship. Just saying. Why can't the overly critic kids not just move on?

Comment: What does "erring up" mean? Moderation is not censorship.

Comment: It's the process of asking questions to get smarter.

Comment: @moestly - thanks. I've never heard that term before. The process of asking questions to get smarter is not understood? Who was "erring up" in this context? You? Folks who asked you questions?