# Reopen request for Workplace reluctant to automate and improve practices Question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, specific-question

I edited this question into a better shape and I want to ask the Community what they think about reopening it:

[Workplace reluctant to automate and improve development practices; what are my options?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/192374/73791)

It was a "should I" question but I rephrased it into something actionable and with a goal. Any other improvements? Is it reopen-worthy now?

Comment: Still need to understand what the heck "The company basically tricked me" means. Hard to suggest any path forward without understanding what actually happened. And it's not clear the OP actually cares. I wouldn't vote to reopen it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original poster were intending to interact positively with the site, I'd say this is getting there. But they're not, so let's just leave it closed.